# Why images not displayed in Drupal7?

Tags: drupal-7

I am using drupal7.12 cms. I have created menu. Menu have sub categories and i have inserted some stories. Issue is that, Images are displayed only on front page of site not on inner pages for that all stories.
If i set any of article to front page image will display for that article on front page. But when i want to read whole story it not showing image. Also when i click on any category then also it only shows text and alternative text for images.
I have stored all images in following folder "/sites/all/images/"  Please help.... Thanks.
I am using JD Events template from http://www.joomlart.com/

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you need adjust the display for your content type. Assuming you are using the article content type go to http://yoursite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display and check the settings for your image field.